# How to add new added people to existing project ? Which API i need to use?

Tags: activecollab

I am using active Collab system to manage my project and using API from my website to add new task, new company, and new user.

My only issue with this is I am not able to add newly added user to my existing project member list.

Please let me know which API i need to call to add newly added user to member list of existing project.

Answer (score 0):

You make a post request to '/projects/{projectId}/members' with user_id payload.

Using the Active Collab Feather SDK:

```
    $client->post('/projects/100/members', [
        "user_id" => $collabId
    ]);
```